# IIS7: Internet explorer cannot display a web page

Tags: windows, iis-7

Hallo,

I am tryiing to migrate an application written with visual studio 2008 from windows XP IIs 6.0 To Windows 7 with IIS 7.5 and I have this problem:

Sometimes when I post the page, the server does not respond and after some minutes i receive e message "Internet explorer can not display a web page"

With IIS 6.0 the application works perfectly.

Please, can you help me ?

Mauro Servi

Answer (score 1):

Try switching the AppPool to Classic .NET mode rather than integrated mode.

You can do this on the Application Pool's Basic Settings in IIS Manager

Comment: I had a similar issue, and this solution worked for me.  Thanks!